# Find sum of linked list F#

Tags: .net, f#

How can i find the sum of elements of a linked list using a function in F#?

Answer (score 10):

F# has a built-in 'linked list' (generic) type - that is just called `list`, and that already has a function to compute the [sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353634.aspx):

```
let list1 = [2; 3; 5]
List.sum list1
```

Arbitrary operations on lists can be written using recursive function:

```
let rec sum l = 
  match l with
    | [] -> 0
    | head::tail -> head + (sum tail)
```

but in most cases it is enough to use the built-in [`fold`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353894.aspx) function:

```
let sum l =
  List.fold (fun total element -> total + element) 0 l
```

Note also that the above 'naïve' recursive function is not [tail-recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion), and so it will crash when applied to very long lists. The tail-recursive implementation would be something like this:

```
let sum l =
  let rec sumAcc acc l = 
    match l with
      | [] -> acc
      | head::tail -> sumAcc (acc+head) tail
  sumAcc 0 l
```

that is basically what `fold` does.

(I am adding this answer in case someone that does not know F# lands on this page - he/she could get a mistaken idea about lists support in F#)

Answer (score 1):

```
let rec sum a = 
    match a with
    |Nil -> 0
    |Link(s,t) -> s+(sum (!t))
```

Comment: I don't think you can have a '_' is allowed in pattern matching, right? where you have _+(sum(!t))

Comment: @JohnOriely I changed it to s just to be sure, have tested it and it works

Comment: I actually incorrectly typed a wrong declaration, that's why it's not working.  Can you look one more time, thanks!

Comment: why are you making rNumber? use int

Comment: well it really has a couple of different types, but I just included the first one.

Comment: Then to make my solution work you need to somehow have `s` be a type that can be added. I don't even know F# I just used the quick interpreter and the evident pattern from your post.

Comment: I don't know f# either! my boss gave me some practice questions where i just started a new job. i might be in trouble..

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example, it doesn't work, so I did fix it.

```
type lists = Nil | Link of (int * (lists ref))

let list1 = Link(3, ref (Link (2, ref Nil)))
let list2 = Link(6, ref (Link (4, ref Nil)))
let list3 = Link(9, ref (Link (6, ref Nil)))

let rec sum = function      // or  let rec sum list = match list with
    | Nil              -> 0
    | Link(head, tail) -> head + sum !tail
```

You don't need to define `Integer of int` , if you do it, you'll have to tag all numbers with `Integer`

Comment: hmm interesting, when I try this, it says the 'h' and 'sum !t' types do not match each other

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure? Try the code from scratch, I just renamed some variables.

Comment: ah I typed the line incorrectly when I declared.                       type rNumber = Integer of int;;
type lists = Nil | Link of (rNumber * (lists ref));;   it's suppose to be "rNumber" not Integer.  That's why I'm getting an error stating the type 'int' does not match 'rNumber'.  How would I get around this? thanks for your help so far!

Comment: If you do it that way, you'll have to write the values like: let list1 = Link(Integer 3, ref (Link (Integer 2, ref Nil)))   but I think it doesn't help to have to prefix all numbers with Integer.

Comment: Hi @JohnOriely if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just for sake of completeness:

```
let sum l =
   l 
   |> List.reduce (+)
```

will also do the trick. Type inference will infer l to be an int list so if you need some other numeric type you can do this (for example a list of longs):

```
let sum (l:list<int64>) =
   l 
   |> List.reduce (+)
```

or this:

```
   let inline sum l =
      l
      |> List.reduce (+)
```

The inline will generalize the sum function to work on any type that provides a static function named "+". To use it, you'd have code like this:

```
let mylist = [1;2;3;4]
let sumOfMyList = sum mylist;;
```

I would also say that in my experience, using list folds and related functions is a better approach than rolling your own recursive functions.